# Strange whiskers in matplotlib?

Tags: python

Lets say I have logn2 np array like  :

```
>>> logn2
array([ -5.        ,   3.22655284,   3.58529678,   5.51257293,
         1.32608097,   1.81131178,   1.61770358,   2.48523293,
         1.52769818,   0.8398167 ,   1.72581258,   0.71002385,
         0.66656821,  15.58947569,   2.66127789,   1.66101225,
         5.93631209,   0.51714802,   1.95765916,   3.8926797 ,   1.78347924])
```

if I do:

```
>>> plt.ion()
>>> plt.figure(1)
>>> bp2 = plt.boxplot(logn2)
>>> axes1 = plt.gca()
>>> axes1.set_ylim([-7,20])
>>> plt.draw()
```

I do not observed the bottom whisker to Q1-1.5(Q3-Q1), as expected ... 
Looking forward for explanation ...
thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2):

The whiskers extend to the furthest *data point* that lies within `1.5*IQR` of the quartile.  They won't extend all the way to `Q1 - 1.5*IQR` unless there is actually a data point there.  For your data:

```
>>> np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
[1.32608097, 1.7834792399999999, 3.2265528400000001]
>>> q1, q2, q3 = np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
>>> iqr = q3-q1
>>> iqr
1.9004718700000001
>>> q1-1.5*iqr
-1.5246268349999998
```

In your data, the further data point between the first quartile and this number is at about 0.5, so that is where the whisker goes.

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't understand this ... so the whiskers appears where is the last data point in the 1.5(Q3-Q1) area, but not at the exact values of Q1-(1.5(Q3-Q1)) and Q3+(1.5(Q3-Q1)) ... thanks  a lot I was lost.

Comment: Again me ... I do not understand other thing :-((( :

Comment: Again me ... I do not understand other thing :-((( :  If I defines >>> y=np.linspace(1., 10, 10) and I do >>>  np.percentile(y, [25, 50, 75]) I obtains [3.25, 5.5, 7.75]. But for me, for the  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 serie, Q3= 5.5 (OK) and Q1=3 (and not 3.25) and Q3=7 (and not 7.75) !!! Sorry I am a little lost with these elementary things ...

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake for the typing of Q3 above: for me it is Q3=8 (and not 7.75)

Comment: @servoz: If you have another question you should post it as a separate question on this site.